# Android: How to move a BitmapDrawable?

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I'm trying to move a `BitmapDrawable` in a custom view. It works fine with a `ShapeDrawable` as follows:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private Drawable image;

    public MyView() {
        image = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        image.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        ((ShapeDrawable) image).getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        image.draw(canvas);
    }

    public void move(int x, int y) {
        Rect bounds = image.getBounds();
        bounds.left += x;
        bounds.right += x;
        bounds.top += y;
        bounds.bottom += y;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

However, if I use a `BitmapDrawable`, the drawable's bounds change, the `onDraw` method is called, but the image stays where it is on the screen.

The following constructor will reproduce the problem by creating a BitmapDrawable instead:

```
public MyView() {
    image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

How can I move a `BitmapDrawable`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation for **Drawable.getBounds()** says the following:

> Note: for efficiency, the returned
>   object may be the same object stored
>   in the drawable (though this is not
>   guaranteed), so if a persistent copy
>   of the bounds is needed, call
>   copyBounds(rect) instead. You should
>   also not change the object returned by
>   this method as it may be the same
>   object stored in the drawable.

This is not cristal clear but it looks like we **must not** change value returned by **getBounds()**, it fires some nasty side effects.

By using **copyBounds()** and **setBounds()** it works like a charm.

```
public void move(int x, int y) {
    Rect bounds = image.copyBounds();
    bounds.left += x;
    bounds.right += x;
    bounds.top += y;
    bounds.bottom += y;
    image.setBounds(bounds);
    invalidate();
}
```

Another way of moving a **Drawable** could be to move the **Canvas** on wich you are drawing:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.translate(x, y);
    image.draw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: But what about the bounds? Why doesn't it work for ImageDrawable while it works perfectly fine for ShapeDrawable?

Comment: I looked into it, and modified my answer explaining why it doesn't work.