# android: how to animate-translate single layer of a LayerDrawable

Tags: android, animation

I've looked through the android animation classes but I'm not sure that I'm seeing what I'm looking for. I was wondering if it is possible to add a translate animation (changing the X coordinates) to a single layer of a LayerDrawable? I found the TranslateAnimation class but it seems like that only works with the entire ImageView, and I just want to animate one single layer of my LayerDrawable. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**In Short:** One can use a [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) to adjust the bounds of that drawable

**In more detail:**
Assuming you have a layer-list drawable, with inner item drawable (`id:innerRed`), and assuming you have a `Button` in your layout (`id:btnWithDrawableBg`) and you have assigned this layered drawable to the `background` property, you can use a [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) to adjust the bounds of that drawable like the example below (ping-pong the `x` position by 100 to each side):

**pos_animator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animator xmlns:andoird="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  andoird:repeatCount="infinite"
  andoird:repeatMode="reverse"
  andoird:valueFrom="-100"
  andoird:valueTo="100"
  andoird:valueType="intType"
/>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // our button with the drawable background
    Button btnWithBg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWithDrawableBg);
    // the layered drawable
    final LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) btnWithBg.getBackground();
    // internal layer (item) drawable with id:innerRed
    final GradientDrawable innerRedShape = (GradientDrawable)layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.innerRed);
    // our animator based on the xml above
    ValueAnimator posAnim = (ValueAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(
            mainLayout.getContext(), R.animator.pos_animator);

    posAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            // get current offset value and adjust drawable bounds
            int value = (Integer)animation.getAnimatedValue();
            Rect bounds = innerRedShape.copyBounds();//see Note below
            // here only manipulating x value
            bounds.offset(value, 0);
            innerRedShape.setBounds(bounds);
        }
    });
    posAnim.setTarget(innerRedShape);
    posAnim.start();
}
```

**Note:** `copyBounds()` is required (and not just `getBounds().offset()`) based on this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270639/android-how-to-move-a-bitmapdrawable)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my answer... it seems that once a LayerDrawable is composed you really can't manipulate the layers. From the lack of responses, I figured that my question is probably asking the wrong thing and I redesigned to use the LayerDrawable but have the animation as individual drawable/imageView objects that I am generating and destroying just before and after each animation. I then use the ObjectAnimator on the imageView to achieve the desired translation of the image. So just in case anyone reads this wanting to animate an individual layer of their LayerDrawable, try to redesign so that you can use the Animator classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way:

**onCreate()**

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Resources r = getResources();

Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];

layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_background_res);

PulseDrawable pulseDrawable = new PulseDrawable(Color.WHITE);
layers[1] = pulseDrawable;

LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

// This will adjust X & Y of layer, we have to pass layer index (250 pixels from Left and 150 pixels from Right)
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 250, 150, 0, 0);

imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

**PulseDrawable.java**

```
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;

public class PulseDrawable extends Drawable {
    private final static float CENTER_AREA_SIZE = 0.6f;
    private final static int PULSE_START_COLOR_OPACITY = 0;
    private final static float MINIMUM_RADIUS = 0;
    private final static int ANIMATION_DURATION_IN_MS = 1500;
    private final int color;
    private Paint centerPaint;
    private Paint pulsePaint;
    private float fullSizeRadius = 60;
    private float currentExpandAnimationValue = 0f;
    private int currentAlphaAnimationValue = 255;

    public PulseDrawable(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        initializeDrawable();
    }

    private void initializeDrawable() {
        preparePaints();
        prepareAnimation();
    }

    private void prepareAnimation() {
        final ValueAnimator expandAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
        expandAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        expandAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        expandAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                currentExpandAnimationValue = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                if (currentExpandAnimationValue == 0f) {
                    currentAlphaAnimationValue = 255;
                }
                invalidateSelf();
            }
        });
        final ValueAnimator alphaAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(255, 0);
        alphaAnimator.setStartDelay(ANIMATION_DURATION_IN_MS / 4);
        alphaAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        alphaAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        alphaAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                currentAlphaAnimationValue = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            }
        });
        AnimatorSet animation = new AnimatorSet();
        animation.playTogether(expandAnimator, alphaAnimator);
        animation.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_IN_MS);
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start();
    }

    private void preparePaints() {
        pulsePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        pulsePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        centerPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        centerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        centerPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        pulsePaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) { }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return pulsePaint.getAlpha();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect bounds = getBounds();

        //TODO - If we want to draw circle on center of canvas use below code

        /*float centerX = bounds.exactCenterX();
        float centerY = bounds.exactCenterY();*/

        float startX = bounds.left;
        float startY = bounds.top;

//        calculateFullSizeRadius();
        preparePaintShader();
        renderPulse(canvas, startX, startY);
        renderCenterArea(canvas, startX, startY);
    }

    private void renderPulse(Canvas canvas, float centerX, float centerY) {
        float currentRadius = fullSizeRadius * currentExpandAnimationValue;
        if (currentRadius > MINIMUM_RADIUS) {
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, currentRadius, pulsePaint);
        }
    }

    private void renderCenterArea(Canvas canvas, float centerX, float centerY) {
        float currentCenterAreaRadius = fullSizeRadius * CENTER_AREA_SIZE;
        if (currentCenterAreaRadius > MINIMUM_RADIUS) {
            canvas.save();
            float left = centerX - currentCenterAreaRadius;
            float top = centerY - currentCenterAreaRadius;
            float right = centerX + currentCenterAreaRadius;
            float bottom = centerY + currentCenterAreaRadius;
            canvas.clipRect(left, top, right, bottom);
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, currentCenterAreaRadius, centerPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }
    private void preparePaintShader() {
        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        float centerX = bounds.exactCenterX();
        float centerY = bounds.exactCenterY();
        float radius = (Math.min(bounds.width(), bounds.height()) / 2);
        if (radius > MINIMUM_RADIUS) {
            int edgeColor = getPulseColor();
            int centerColor = Color.argb(PULSE_START_COLOR_OPACITY, Color.red(color),
                    Color.green(color),
                    Color.blue(color));
            pulsePaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(centerX, centerY, radius,
                    centerColor, edgeColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        } else {
            pulsePaint.setShader(null);
        }
    }

    private int getPulseColor() {
        return Color.argb(currentAlphaAnimationValue, Color.red(color),
                Color.green(color),
                Color.blue(color));
    }

    private void calculateFullSizeRadius() {
        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        float minimumDiameter = Math.min(bounds.width(), bounds.height());
        fullSizeRadius = (minimumDiameter / 2);
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Note:** You can add multiple layers, for demo I have added two layers.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What is the imageView? Only of the static circle with the pulse? And what is your_background_res ? The static circle?